# Fast hash function for IPv4/6 addresses

Tags: c, hash, hashtable, ip-address, hash-function

I'm writing program in C, which is **designed to be fast**.

I want to store the number of occurrences of IP addresses in the data flow. For example I will analyse 100MB binary file, which contains about 2 000 000 IP addresses (but maybe program will be used also for x-GB files).

My idea is use hash tables, so I need these hash functions:

```
20b_int indexToIPv4HashTable = hashIPv4(32b_int addr4);
20b_int indexToIPv6HashTable = hashIPv6(128b_int addr6);
```

I think it isn't problem when this functions will have collision sometime (I will resolve this using Separate chaining).

- *Which hash functions should I use?*
- *It is good idea using hash table for this issue?*

Little maths:

- 20b index = 1 048 576 elements (*Is it enough?*)
- 32b element = 4B element = 4MB table size (*Is This size OK, when program will run on
  present computers?*)

Note:
IP addresses may have specified a mask. For example: IPv4/24 --> now there is only 2^24 different IPv4 addresses instead of 2^32. *Should I use different hash table size, when mask is set?*

**Absolutely priority is speed.**

Comment: Is there any correlation between addr[i] and addr[i+n], where n is small? This may be a crucial factor when determining how well the hash function must scramble the bits. In I7 it's quite hard to beat crc32 instruction (or a combination of polynomial multiplication) in speed, but it's the overall performance that matters.

Answer (score 3):

*By the way, I am assuming you meant 4Gb, not 4Mb for the 32-bit index size above. Also, that assumes that you only need one byte per entry (max of 255 hits)*

It is hard to know which hash will be better without knowing the distribution of addresses. If they are more or less randomly spread over the address space (and, yes, I know that most IPv6 addresses are not allocated), just pick a few bits of the address and use that.

As an example, pick five 4-bit areas spread evenly in the address for ipv4 and the lowest 16 bits + 4 bits from somewhere in the middle for v6.

But if you are on a modern x86 using the crc32 instruction will almost certainly produce a good enough hash, and it is fast.

```
#define HASH_MASK ((1<<20)-1)

static inline int hash32( unsigned int foo )
{
  return __builtin_ia32_crc32si( 0, foo ) & HASH_MASK;
}

static inline int hash128( const char *data )
{
  int res = 0, i;
  for( i=0; i<4; i++, data+=4 )
    res = __builtin_ia32_crc32si( res, *(int32_t *)data ); 
  return res & HASH_MASK;
}
```

Note that this is highly unportable, not only does it only work on x86, it only works on some x86 machines (it also requires -msse4.2 if you are using gcc).

One note: *Unless you are processing a lot of entries per second (and I do mean a lot) the speed of the hash function is unlikely to matter.
The spread of data in the hash buckets could affect things, but even a simple non-resizing implementation of a linked-list bucket hash table will be able to process at least hundreds of millions of hits per second unless the links get to be 100+ long.
In fact, the speed of the hard-drive the file is read from is most likely to be the limiting factor.*